# Does row major form exist for vectors?

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, vector, std

It's very clear that row major form of a 2D array is a single array stored such that different rows are aligned in sequence.

To traverse any element of the 2d array I can always do :

```
int a[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

for(int i=0;i<3*3;i++){

cout<<*(*a+i)<<" "; //row major form concept where i<m*n;

}
```

gives:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

It completely works for me but whenever I do this with a vector it throws me an error:

```
vector<vector<int> > v={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

int m=v.size();
int n=v[0].size();
for(int i=0;i<m*n;i++){

cout<<*(*v+i)<<" ";

}
```

It gives :

```
no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::vector<std::vector<int> >)
```

I hope that vectors do follow the row major form concept as arrays. If yes than what is alternative for row major in case of a vector?

Comment: thanks for correction, that was my perception which I wrote in a wrong way apology. But still the main question is independent of that part.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are on the wrong track. Since `std::vector` allocates memory dynamically on the free-store, there is no such thing as row-major or column-major.

Memory for a 2d-array `int foo[][]{ { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }` starting at `&foo[0]`:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Visualized:

```
+------+
| foo  |
+------+ 
|  1   |
|  2   |
|  3   |
|  4   |
|  5   |
|  6   |
+------+
```

Memory for a `std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo{ { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }`:

somewhere (unrelated to `&foo`):

```
1, 2, 3
```

somewhere else:

```
4, 5, 6
```

Visualized:

```
                                                             +------+
                                                        +--> | int  |
+-------------------------+                             |    +------|
| foo                     |                             |    |  1   |
+-------------------------+       +------------------+  |    |  2   |
| std::vector<int> *data -|-----> | std::vector<int> |  |    |  3   |           
+-------------------------+       +------------------+  |    +------+      
                                  | int* data[0]-----|--+
                                  | int* data[1]-----|--+    +------+
                                  +------------------+  +--> | int  |
                                                             +------+
                                                             |  4   |
                                                             |  5   |
                                                             |  6   |
                                                             +------+
```

To traverse your `std::vector` of `std::vector`s:

```
for (auto const &v_item : v) {
    for (auto const &i : v_item) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
std::cout.put('\n');
```